# iptables show ACCEPT but connection got refused

Tags: networking, server, iptables, port-forwarding

I have a Django application accessible at port 8080. My current iptables is set

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:redis
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:9443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:8000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:8086
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.5           tcp dpt:3000
```

basically all my POLICIES are on ACCEPT but for some reason, if I access from any of my coputer on the local network with :8080 I got a connection refused. If I access from inside the localhost everything works fine.

What's blocking the connection on that port? Even if I change port (expect from port 80, I always get rejected)

I'm running ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: What do the logs show?

Comment: @OrganicMarble how can i log?